# MySQL Query to return all products and the SKU without a thumbnail

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I found a very similar topic on here from a long while back where the poster was asking for a way of returning all products in WooCommerce that didn't have a thumbnail (ie no image).

That works great, but what I also want to return is the SKU for the product, which also exists in the wp_postmeta table.

How would I adjust the query below to return that?

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title

FROM wp_posts as p LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')

WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND (meta_key IS NULL OR meta_value = "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Think I've answered my own question after messing around!

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta1.meta_value as SKU 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (wp_posts.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id') 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1 on wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID and wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku' 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (pm.meta_key IS NULL OR pm.meta_value = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

With *$wpdb->get_results* you can use:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_title, wp_postmeta1.meta_value as SKU FROM $wpdb->posts p
            LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON (p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id') 
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wp_postmeta1 on wp_postmeta1.post_id = p.ID and wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku' 
            WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND (pm.meta_key IS NULL OR pm.meta_value = '')");
```